# Best way to store large amount of files

Tags: .net, database

Is there any db system to store large amount of files?
The files are compressed web pages?

In SQL systems the problem raise where db size grow and I want to make a backup or a simple `insert` or `select` get slower. I know I can write thousands of code and manage this problem or create another databases to keep databases small.

But I want a db system that cover all these problems automatically. (I want to do more with less!!)

Thanks

Comment: As always, it depends on what you want to do. Do you just want to store the files? Make backups? Run SQL queries?

Comment: @Nodebody : just simple query like select file from table where id = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest MS SQL Server has a special [FILESTREAM](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/40812) feature, where files are stored *through* the database as if they were blobs, but they are actually stored in a separate folder. I think this is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: dude, you just made my week! Thats an amazing feature. How about performance for this: is there any disadvantages (int terms of performance) compared to an approach where the DB stores filepaths to the files on disk?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to store thousands of files is (gasp) on a file-system. If you need a hybrid, have you considered the [FILESTREAM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) type in sql server?